# How is Green's function used in converting differential equations into integral one

Tags: electromagnetism, calculus, greens-functions

[image]

I was reading this section of W. C. Gibson, The Method of Moments in Electromagnetics, Second. Chapman and Hall/CRC, 2014, and I was confused on how they got from 2.25 to 2.26

It seems the integrand in 2.26 is the integrand of 2.24 multplied by Green's function at a particular point $r$'.  Why is this called the "response of a point source?" Why does integrating it solve for Ex?

My math background is only Calculus III, which I took years ago so I may have forgotten something. Is there a math text you can recommend so I understand this math?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Picture 2]

And here is image 2 (with 30 characters)

Answer (score 0):

[image: Page1]

Hope this helps. Two separate images.

Comment: Hello! It is [preferable](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10563/) to type out screenshots; for formulae, one can use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/). Thanks!